I have a 9 1/2 inch long red eared slider who has started laying eggs for the first time! How long will she lay eggs and how many?
She is around 6 years old and never layed eggs before. She has layed 4 so far

This question is similar to: Red eared slider laying eggs into the water. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
